# Get a mysql row if value (user_id) exists in JSON column

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I can't seem to understand how to check if an ID exists in my JSON column in my table.

Let me give you an idea on how my layout is.

I have a table called teams, this table of course includes a list of all my teams. In this table I have a column which is of type JSON named "aMembers". This includes a JSON with IDs of users that are members of this team.

Example JSON:

```json
{
    "user_id" : [18, 55, 81, 26, 65]
}
```

Now let's say that I'm logged in as user 26. How would my query look like if I would like to get ALL teams where user with id 26 exists in column "aMembers" which is of type JSON?

Example response that I am looking for:

```json
{
    "Team1": {
        "name": "Team1",
        "description": "Team1 Description",
        "created_at": "2020-05-20T12:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-20T12:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Team88": {
        "name": "Team88",
        "description": "Team88 Description",
        "created_at": "2020-05-20T12:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-20T12:00:00.000Z"
    },
}
```

Mysql version 5.7

Comment: Thats not valid JSON, should be `{"ids": [12,13,14,15]}`. And what have you tried?

Comment: @Firewizz Changed my example. My bad, I hand wrote that json. 
I have not tried anything much right now. I've mostly been googling and seeing if I could understand how to use the JSON column type but I cant seem to get a grasp around it.

Comment: *Example response that I am looking for* ??? Shown desired responce cannot be obtained from shown tiny source data. Provide complete example - source data stored in MySQl (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO), external input criteria/data (JSON object with numbers array? something else?) and desired output for this source data and criteria. Also specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina Yeah, my ways of giving examples are pretty broken. 
My idea is something like this SELECT *  from TABLE where 26 EXISTS in JSON COLUMN? I know that it isnt a valid query but that should give an idea what I am looking for. 

I am going to add the version in a second. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: You may test does some value is present in shown JSON using functions JSON_CONTAINS(), JSON_OVERLAPS(), JSON_SEARCH()... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html

Comment: JSON_CONTAINS() did it. Thanks. It is pretty much in the word itself but I just didnt know anything about it haha.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4af463193938ee508b92848737a90bab

Answer (score 1):

Me being dumb totally overestimated how hard this would be and simply scared myself from trying too much. Stupid idea. I learnt how simple it was.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(aMembers, '26');
```

works totally fine with. My aMebers column has a value of

```json
[26, 66, 1]
```

(directly copied from the column).

This works and returns everything I needed. Thanks to everyone who gave their shots and assisted.

Learn more here: https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/